# How to add files to a mercurial repository after they were deleted

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repository. I removed a folder that contained a lot of subfolders and files from it and made a commit.

Now, when I try to to add a folder that has the same name that also contains huge amount of files and subfolders, mercurial doesn't see these new files.

I tried **hg add folder_name**, **hg add folder_name/** and even **hg add folder_name/*** but **hg status** displays nothing after that.

What is wrong?

**UPD:** I tried to add a new folder with a different name withoud deleting the old one: **hg add service/resources/skels/0.92/*** but that didn't add files that are in subfolders of 0.92 folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following session with Mercurial 1.7.1 demonstrates that removing and re-adding a folder is normally not a problem:

```
D:\hg>hg init test
D:\hg>cd test
D:\hg\test>mkdir folder
D:\hg\test>echo foo > folder/foo
D:\hg\test>hg add folder
adding folder\foo
D:\hg\test>hg ci -m "added folder"
D:\hg\test>hg rm folder
removing folder\foo
D:\hg\test>hg ci -m "removed folder"
D:\hg\test>mkdir folder
D:\hg\test>echo foo > folder/foo
D:\hg\test>hg add folder
adding folder\foo
D:\hg\test>hg status
A folder\foo
D:\hg\test>hg ci -m "added folder again"
```

Can you show such a sequence of commands which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you made an error during your original deletion/commit.

Try removing **folder_name** entirely, then doing a commit and verify it's completely removed from the latest changeset.  Then move **folder_name** back into the repo.  You should then be able to `hg add folder_name`.